# Using Fiddler to identify what is hitting sites

Tags: fiddler

Something on my computer is randomly calling a couple SharePoint sites.  The last time the mystery process ran, it made 20K calls to a couple different SharePoint sites.

I tried closing Outlook, OneNote, Designer, and other apps that were running. No Task Schedules are set to run around the time this happened.

Using Fiddler, is there a way to identify what is making a call to a site?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at the `Process` column to find out what process is issuing the request. You will likely either see one of the Office applications (which periodically refresh a registry-based list of SharePoint sites you've used) or a `svchost.exe` instance. If it's a svchost.exe instance, you'll need to use a tool like Process Explorer (or the Win8+ Task Manager) to see which services are running within the svchost.exe with the specified process ID.